# Need to pass model to a method, modify it, and send it back to calling method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to find a more efficient way in modifying the data inside of my model when passed to different methods.

I've got the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public double foo {get;set;} 
  public double foo2 {get;set;}
  public double foo3 {get;set;}
}
```

in my data class I'm going to my database, getting the ID and inserting it into my model. Beacuse there are multiple ID's, I then add this to a list<> of MyModel:

```
List<MyModel> Lots = new List<MyModel>();

...Using statement to make the database connection...

 while (dtrSQL.Read())
                    {
                        MyModel Lot = new MyModel();
                        Lot.LotName = dtrSQL["LotName"].ToString();
                        Lots.Add(Lot);
                     }
```

After the Database connection closes, I want to send Lots into a new method and calculate foo for each item and bring back the original data along with foo. I would like to do something like this, but don't know if it is possible:

```
Lots = CalculateFoo(Lots);
```

And my CaclculateFoo Method:

```
public List<MyModels> CalcualteFoo(List<MyModels> values){
 foreach (var i in values)
      values[1].foo = 1;

  return values;
 }
```

I obviously can do this if I instantiate a new class of type List, set it equal to the object returned by CalculateFoo method, and loop through this and assign it to my Lots model (see below code), but was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

```
List<MyModel> ScratchLot = new List<MyModel>();

ScratchLot = CalculateFoo(Lots);
Foreach (var i in ScratchLot){
  Lots[i].foo = ScratchLot[i].foo;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to return the list, it is the same list you have provided as an argument. The same goes for the entries inside the list. You are working on the same objects (no copy/clone is being made).

Comment: @Program - Worked perfectly. Knew it would be something simple!

Comment: @Progman is perfectly correct, but still mutating input parameters is something that has to be considered carefully, as it introduces side effects in your code. Since you are doing an update, you should argue that whatever comes back is an updated model, and should no longer be the same at that time. More efficient here is from my point of view not a very useful question to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you want to improve the performance on the approach. Given that you already have the list populated in-memory, there's no way to do this faster than the **CalculateFoo** method you have there.

Changing values in-place in an already existing list of object references will always be faster (at least in C#) than re-assigning a new list and populating it with new objects.

Even if you did that, a big performance improvement would be initializing the **List** with the number of values you know it would contain:

```
List<T> list = new List<T>(originalList.Length);
```

This way, the CLR can already allocate a memory address big enough to hold all the necessary object references to hold all the new objects (because, of course, a List has an Array in the background). But, reallocating the memroy for the references isn't enough, the CLR will also need to create all those new instances of the **MyModel** instances, copy the values you **already** have in your existing list, and then update them.

I know immutability is hot right now, but in some cases it just doesn't make sense to apply it, especially if you have performance concerns.